# How to fit video preview to fill Image View Xcode Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation

I am trying to implement a feature in my app that allows a user to take a profile picture. Using AVFoundation, I can easily output the video preview layer to the full screen. I also tried setting the preview layer frame to imageview frame, but it gave me the results shown in the photo below.

```
    if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession){
        self.previewLayer = previewLayer

        //this is for full screen output
        //self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        //self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame

        //this gives me the result in the photo
        cameraOutputImageView.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        self.previewLayer.frame = cameraOutputImageView.layer.frame

        captureSession.startRunning()
        print("trying to run capture session")

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]

        dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput){
            captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
        }

        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    }
```

However, I want the video feed to be a square that is the size of the image view it's meant to fill. Here is how it looks now: [image]

The pink box is what needs to be filled with the image. Right now it only displays that camera output near the top left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting the preview layer to the imageview bounds

`self.previewLayer.frame = cameraOutputImageView.layer.bounds`

You have to make sure you call the camera function after all the subviews have loaded if you are using autolayout constraints because the layer.bounds of the uiimage only changes after viewDidLayoutSubviews has been called.